# Center the slider on the homepage

Tags: html, slider, center

I tried a thousand things, but I can't center my slider.
This is the website; http://www.equiphotography.nl/Dreamweaver/index2.html

Can anyone help me?

I can email my HTML code if that is necessary.

Jill

Comment: post some of the code that you have tried so far here, and perhaps start a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) to show/test some code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't your slider, the real problem is your IMG.

The slider is already centered, but your img is a 830*405, or your body is 1200.

You see what i mean? Take another IMGs for your slider, you can change the IMGs' width of course but it extends the IMG.

You have 2 options:
- You take another IMGs but 1200*800 or 1200*450 (whatever, only 1200 is important).
- You change your IMGs with Photoshop or else.

Answer (score 0):

please add this line to your css file

```
#cp_widget_171752bb-6c39-4448-9bc5-49b0863aa9b6{margin: 0px auto;}
```

It will work Fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set some css for the slide

```
#cp_widget_171752bb-6c39-4448-9bc5-49b0863aa9b6{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Because Your container width is `width: 1200px;` so `margin: auto` will center the slide on your container. Hope this will helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
    ....
    .........
   <div class="flexslider">place the slider</div>
    .....
    ......
 </div>
</body>
```

css :

```
.container
{
width:1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
.flexslider
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove Inline style in #cp_widget_171752bb-6c39-4448-9bc5-49b0863aa9b6

and add class in your css

```
#cp_widget_171752bb-6c39-4448-9bc5-49b0863aa9b6{
 margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 830px;
width: 830px;
```

}

may be it will be helpful